# WebGL Element Array Buffers not working

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, haxe

I'm learning WebGL with haxe and I'm stuck on the part describing element arrays. What is suppose to be a square isn't showing up and I dont know why?

```
var verticesArray = [   
                             0.5, 0.5,      
                             0.5,-0.5,  
                            -0.5,-0.5, 
                            -0.5, 0.5   
                        ];

    var indicesArray = [0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3];

    var VBO = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(verticesArray), GL.STATIC_DRAW);

    var EBO = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,  new UInt16Array(indicesArray), GL.STATIC_DRAW);

    GL.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    GL.useProgram(shaderProgram);


    GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

Here's all the code that's suppose to draw the square I have got the shader programing working for sure

Comment: a 16 bit integer is usually referred to as `short`, not as `int`. in fact, for 32 bit integer indices you'd need the `OES_element_index_uint` extension.

Comment: also, you may not let that vertexAttribPointer wander off too far from the VBO it describes or you will be back tomorrow, after adding another VBO wondering why the pointers don't work any more after you've bound another buffer to that target.

Comment: @Winchestro thanks that worked, and I moved the vertexattribPointer back next to the VBO calls

Comment: glad I could help. I guess I could as well formulate it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the type in your call to `drawElements` matches the provided index array type, which is

- `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` for `Uint8Array`
- `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` for `Uint16Array`
- `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` for `Uint32Array` (needs `OES_element_index_uint` extension)

Also `VertexAttribPointer` and `enableVertexAttribArray` calls always operate on the buffer currently bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` target, which in this case isn't a problem, but very well become one the way you wrote it if you add additional VBOs. So either set them after creating and binding the buffer or make otherwise sure the correct buffer is bound.